# How to have multiple pictures use the Modal.js?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have images in a div side by side that I'd like to open in their own Modal pop up, this is what I'm using so far

**HTML**

```
        <div id="thumbs">


    <!-- IMG1 popup -->
   <img id="myImg" src="img/img1.jpg" alt="thumbnail" style="width:100%;max- 
   width:150px" />
   <!-- The Modal -->
   <div id="myModal" class="modal">

   <!-- The Close Button -->
   <span class="close">&times;</span>

   <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
   <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

   <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
   <div id="caption"></div>
   </div>
   <!-- End IMG -->


    <!-- IMG2 popup -->
   <img id="myImg" src="img/img2.jpg" alt="thumbnail" style="width:100%;max- 
   width:150px" />
   <!-- The Modal -->
   <div id="myModal" class="modal">

   <!-- The Close Button -->
   <span class="close">&times;</span>

   <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
   <img class="modal-content" id="img02">

   <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
   <div id="caption"></div>
   </div>
   <!-- End IMG -->



     </div>
```

**JS**

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a 
caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

I've tried a couple lines like this and it's still broken, I've tried doubling the whole block of js, and it only loads on the first one and wont show the image either, so far I've only been able to get it to work with only one image, I need the same effect to work on about 32 images ultimately in the thumbs DIV above

```
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img02");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using same ID multiple times (which is not allowed) in the document. For example: myModal, myImg

Numbered the ID attribute for each image & modal so they will have different ID. For example:

```
<img id="myImg1"...
<div id="myModal1"...
<img id="myImg2"...
<div id="myModal2"...
```

or use only one modal, and change modal content based on values you get from image. Like this:

```
<img onclick="insert(this)" class="img" src="img/img1.jpg"...
<img onclick="insert(this)" class="img" src="img/img2.jpg"...
<div id="myModal"...
  <img class="modal-content" id="img">
...

function insert(ctl) {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = ctl.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = ctl.alt;
}
```

Hope this helps!